# Flip normals or delete geometry? For better overall performance

Tags: uv, normals

This is certainly a **noob** question but I haven't found a solid answer yet.

Say I have a 50 face, UV mapped object ready to be imported to a game engine.

Only 40 of the 50 faces will be visible, the remaining 10 faces are still UV mapped

Obviously I don't want to render the parts that aren't visible so,

Is it better for general performance to just delete the 10 faces  **or** leave them UV mapped with the normals flipped? If I flipped the normals, does that mean those parts wont render? Or will it make no difference?

Thanks.

Comment: Why does your model have parts that are never seen? Out of view, normal flipped faces are still loaded and consuming memory regardless of visibility or uv mapping, if they are unnecessary why leave them? That being said 10 faces sound like it is hardly a problem.

Comment: I just used 10 faces as an example. So the UV data is still loaded when the Normals are flipped huh? @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: Hypothetical questions are not a very good fit for Stack Exchange. Flipping normals is a modeling tool not an optimization technique, flipping faces only makes them invisible from one side, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple, yet very true rule in game design:
- Remove anything the player will never see or use.

UV data is still loaded, vertices are still calculated, there is still a check to see if the face is visible. Everything except the final step, which is 'visualising the face'.